# How to retrieve data from many to many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models like this:

```
class GuestStatus(models.Model):
    guest_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arrangement = models.IntegerField(unique=True, help_text="Start from 1. Guest status will be arranged alphabetically.")

class Guest(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    status = models.ManyToManyField(GuestStatus, blank=True, null=True)
    invitation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to retrieve data in template:

```
#Views.py:
guests = Guest.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

# Template:
 {% for guest in guests %}
    <tr>
    <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ guest.id }}" name="guest_name" id="{{ forloop.counter }}" /></td>
    <td><a href="/{{ guest.id }}/guest/">{{ guest.full_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ guest.guests }}</td>
    <td>{{ guest.children }}</td>
    <td>{% for i in guest.gueststatus_set.all %}{{ i.status }}{% endfor %}</td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is not giving any result for `gueststatus`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `ManyToMany` you don't get `_set`, change your query to `guest.status.all()`, also use `{{i.guest_status}}` as `GuestStatus` has `guest_status` not `status`.

```
<td>{% for i in guest.status.all %}{{ i.status }}{% endfor %}</td>
```

Comment: <td>{% for i in guest.status.all %}{{ i.guest_status }}{% endfor %}</td> as gueststatus has guest_status field no status.

Comment: Thanks fellas. But how to do this while update. I am sure as hell "`status = form.cleaned_data['status'] Guest.objects.filter(id=guest_id).update(status=status)` doesn't work.

Comment: @user2032220, no M2M cannot be updated like that, you need to do `.add()`, `.remove()` etc.

Comment: How do I know if they remove or add? Can you add this in your answer. I will mark answer correct then.

Comment: @user2032220, refer this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ You should post another question detailing what you are trying and the problem.

Comment: I posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701839/update-manytomanyfield-in-django-from-form-data